# Animating axes size and 2 sequential animations in python and matplotlib

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I am teaching myself python math animation so I don't even know if what I'm asking is possible with matplotlib.  What I want is 
(1)for the axes to start off small then expand.  After this, I want it to 
(2) plot two lines sequentially (one after the other) rather than concurrently (at the same time) which is what it is doing.
My code is below except for my attempts to expand the axes (at best my attempts didn't crash python).

```
import time 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
#from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation


maxsize = 8
size = 1
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(maxsize, maxsize))
# fig will start at "size" if I ever figure out the animation
xmin = -10
xmax = 10
ymin = -10
ymax = 10
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(xmin, xmax), ylim=(ymin, ymax))
plt.axhline(linewidth=3, color='black')
plt.axvline(linewidth=3, color='black')
line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2)


def init1():
    line.set_data([], [])
    return line,

def animate1(i):
    x1 = np.linspace(-10, i/5 - 10, 1000)
    y1 = -1*x1
    line.set_data(x1, y1)
    return line,

def init2():
    line.set_data([], [])
    return line,

def animate2(j):
    x2 = np.linspace(0, j/10, 1000)
    y2 = 2*x2
    line.set_data(x2, y2)
    return line,

plt.grid()
plt.xticks(np.arange(xmin, xmax+1, 1.0))
plt.yticks(np.arange(ymin, ymax+1, 1.0))

anim1 = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate1, init_func=init1, 
    frames=100, interval=20, blit=True) 
plt.plot() 
plt.show()
time.sleep(1)
anim2 = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate2, init_func=init2, 
    frames=100, interval=20, blit=True)
plt.plot() 
plt.show()
```

So I guess my questions are:
Is what I want to do possible in matplotlib?  One?  The other? Both?
If so, how do I do it.

Comment: It is not very clear to me what you want; let's try to clarify: `(1)for the axes to start off small then expand` is this some sort of zooming effect on the number line? `(2) plot two lines sequentially rather than concurrently` You want to plot one line, then the other line, on the same plot (retaining the first line)? or you want to show one plot with the first, then another with the second?

Comment: (1) I want the axes to start of small, let's say 1" by 1" then grow to 8" by 8".  (2) I want to draw one line on a plot, pause, then draw a second line on the same plot.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you could chain your three steps together, I'm not sure there an elegant way.

However, I experimented with creating a "growing" Axes with the code below:

```
fig_size_w = 9  # inches
fig_size_h = 9  # inches
ax_bottom_x = 0.1  # fig fraction
ax_bottom_y = 0.1  # fig fraction
ax_init_x = 0.1  # fig fraction
ax_init_y = 0.1  # fig fraction
ax_final_x = 0.9  # fig fraction
ax_final_y = 0.9  # fig fraction
grow_steps = 100  # number of steps in the growing process
xmin = -10
xmax = 10
ymin = -10
ymax = 10

grow_step_x = (ax_final_x - ax_init_x)/grow_steps
grow_step_y = (ax_final_y - ax_init_y)/grow_steps

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(fig_size_w, fig_size_h))
ax = fig.add_axes([ax_bottom_x, ax_bottom_y, 0, 0])

def init():
    ax.axhline(linewidth=3, color='black')
    ax.axvline(linewidth=3, color='black')
    ax.grid()
    ax.set_xticks(np.arange(xmin, xmax+1, 1.0))
    ax.set_yticks(np.arange(ymin, ymax+1, 1.0))

def animate(i):
    ax.set_position([ax_bottom_x, ax_bottom_y, (i+1)*grow_step_x, (i+1)*grow_step_y])


anim = matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=grow_steps, init_func=init, interval=10)
```

[image]

## EDIT

Actually, I was thinking about this problem today, and I had the thought of creating a master `animate()` function, which would accept as parameter a dictionary containing a list of frames, and a function pointer to execute for each frame.
The code could be improved a lot, but this proof of concept works:

```
fig_size_w = 9  # inches
fig_size_h = 9  # inches
ax_bottom_x = 0.1  # fig fraction
ax_bottom_y = 0.1  # fig fraction
ax_init_x = 0.1  # fig fraction
ax_init_y = 0.1  # fig fraction
ax_final_x = 0.9  # fig fraction
ax_final_y = 0.9  # fig fraction
grow_steps = 100  # number of steps in the growing process
xmin = -10
xmax = 10
ymin = -10
ymax = 10

grow_step_x = (ax_final_x - ax_init_x)/grow_steps
grow_step_y = (ax_final_y - ax_init_y)/grow_steps

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(fig_size_w, fig_size_h))
ax = fig.add_axes([ax_bottom_x, ax_bottom_y, 0, 0])
line, = ax.plot([],[], lw=2)

def init():
    ax.axhline(linewidth=3, color='black')
    ax.axvline(linewidth=3, color='black')
    ax.grid()
    ax.set_xticks(np.arange(xmin, xmax+1, 1.0))
    ax.set_yticks(np.arange(ymin, ymax+1, 1.0))

def animate(i, func_dict):
    a = []
    for max_i,func in func_dict.items():
        if i < max_i:
            a = func(i)
            break
    return a

def func_grow(i):
    ax.set_position([ax_bottom_x, ax_bottom_y, (i+1)*grow_step_x, (i+1)*grow_step_y])
    return []

def func_pause(i):
    pass
    return []

def func_line1(i):
    i-=(grow_steps+100)  # need to remove offset value in i for it to start at 0
    x1 = np.linspace(-10, i/5 - 10, 1000)
    y1 = -1*x1
    line.set_data(x1, y1)
    return line,

def func_line2(j):
    j-=(grow_steps+300)  # need to remove offset value in j for it to start at 0
    x2 = np.linspace(0, j/10, 1000)
    y2 = 2*x2
    line.set_data(x2, y2)
    return line,


anim = matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=grow_steps+400, init_func=init, interval=10, 
                                          fargs=({grow_steps: func_grow,
                                                  grow_steps+100: func_pause,
                                                  grow_steps+200: func_line1,
                                                  grow_steps+300: func_pause,
                                                  grow_steps+400: func_line2},))
```

[image: 3 animations in one!]

NB: I had to reduce the size of the figure to fit under the size restriction of imgur